# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 434852: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, xml

I am using hfcca to calculate cyclomatic complexity for a c++ code. hfcca is a simple python script (https://code.google.com/p/headerfile-free-cyclomatic-complexity-analyzer/). When i am trying to run the script to generate the output in the form of an xml file i am getting following errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    "./hfcca.py", line 802, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
    File "./hfcca.py", line 798, in main
    print(xml_output([f for f in r], options))
    File "./hfcca.py", line 798, in <listcomp>
    print(xml_output([f for f in r], options))
    File "/x/home06/smanchukonda/PREFIX/lib/python3.3/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 652, in next
    raise value
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 434852: invalid continuation byte
```

Please help me with this..

Comment: The program says the XML contains an invalid character so we would need to see the XML

Answer (score 11):

The problem looks like the file has characters represented with latin1 that aren't characters in utf8. The `file` utility can be useful for figuring out what encoding a file should be treated as, e.g:

```
monk@monk-VirtualBox:~$ file foo.txt 
foo.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Here's what the bytes mean in latin1:

```
>>> b'\xe2'.decode('latin1')
'â'
```

Probably easiest is to convert the files to utf8.

Comment: â is 0xe2, one of the urf-8 bit patterns introducing multi-byte codes. the successor byte(s) would be more interesting. anyway, you're right that it's most probably easiest to convert the whole file to utf-8.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem rendering Markup("""yyyyyy""") but i solved it using an online tool with removed the 'bad' characters. https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/

It is a nice tool and works even offline.